# How to access environment-specific Firebase Function endpoints from Firebase Hosted application?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I have three Firebase projects representing Development, Staging and Production environments hosted on Firebase hosting. Each environment utilizes its own deployed Firebase functions like so:

- Dev function endpoint: https://us-central1-my-app-dev.cloudfunctions.net/someFunction
- Staging function endpoint: https://us-central1-my-app-staging.cloudfunctions.net/someFunction
- Production function endpoint: https://us-central1-my-app.cloudfunctions.net/someFunction

I can't figure out how the static, Firebase-hosted client React application should invoke these functions because the URI endpoints of each changes depending on which environment the code is executing from.

Ideally I could set environment-specific configuration for each Firebase Hosting environment; unfortunately [the only way to do this in Firebase Hosting is from within Firebase Functions themselves](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env).

How can I retrieve the environment-specific endpoint for each Firebase Function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple options here.

First, you could just configure your React app any way you like.  It's necessarily not a bad thing for each system component (backend, frontend) to have its own configuration.

Second, since you're using Firebase Hosting to serve your static content, you can also use it to [serve your functions API endpoints](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#direct_hosting_requests_to_your_function).  This means that both your static content and API endpoints are all served through the same hostname, which means you no longer have to specify the host when making a request.  All the requests can be relative to that host.  You can achieve this via Hosting rewrite rules.