# How to get the firebase functions URL in a firebase hosted webapp?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I am working on a project in which we have pre-existing cloud functions in use with Firebase. We are adding a small React SPA using firebase cloud hosting, and this SPA will interact with some of the existing public cloud functions.

The way we have been doing things so far, we have a dev project, and a production project in Firebase. For cloud functions, this works fine, we have environment specific config set up with `firebase functions:config:set` for differentiations between prod and dev servers.

The problem comes with the hosted SPA contacting the cloud functions. I've seen a lot of questions on how to access the environment config in the hosted code, eg this one: [How to reference Firebase Functions config variables from a Firebase-hosted application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48967122/how-to-reference-firebase-functions-config-variables-from-a-firebase-hosted-appl) where the answer seems to be to have firebase functions that return the values of the environment variables, but for me this just moves the problem further back on step. I fully understand that having the environment variables accessible to this code would be a massive security problem as the SPA is run in the browser.

The only environment specific config I really need for the hosted SPA is the base address for the cloud functions.

eg if in my cloud functions I have

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const test = express();
test.on('/hello/:target', (req, res) => {
  res.send(`Hello ${req.params.target}`);
})
exports.test = functions.https.onRequest(test);
```

then having deployed, this cloud function is available both at https://us-central1-DEV-PROJECT-NAME.cloudfunctions.net/test/hello/world and https://us-central1-PROD-PROJECT-NAME.cloudfunctions.net/test/hello/world . How would I best get the appropriate root url (https://us-central1-DEV-PROJECT-NAME.cloudfunctions.net or https://us-central1-PROD-PROJECT-NAME.cloudfunctions.net) for the project that the SPA is deployed to?

eg. is there some global I can access in the frontend js code where I could do something like:

```
const url = `${__FIREBASE_GLOBALS__.cloudFunctions.baseUrl}/test/hello/${input}`;
```

And have the url be correctly defined based on which project the hosted app is deployed to?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming here that you're not using Firebase in any other way in your SPA other than to call Cloud Functions (since you didn't say otherwise).

Read the [Firebase web setup docs for Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#host_your_web_app_using_firebase_hosting), especially the section on [SDK imports and implicit initialization](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#sdk_imports_and_implicit_initialization).  When you host a site with Firebase Hosting, there are some special URLs that give you the configurations for that project.  There are some special script includes that give you access to Firebase products.  In particular, note the relative path URI `/__/firebase/init.js` will yield JavaScript that initializes the Firebase JavaScript SDK with the default settings for your project.  Go ahead and access that in a browser pointing to your web app.  You're probably interested in the `projectId` property of the config.

If you want to get a hold of that value, you can use the Firebase SDK, which would be initialized by the script includes from the first link above.  Minimally, you could add:

```
<script src="/__/firebase/5.8.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
```

Then later on ([see API docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.app.App#options)):

```
firebase.app().options.projectId
```

to get the ID of the project where Firebase Hosting is serving the content.  You can use that to build the URL to your functions.

It might also be convenient for you to port your HTTP functions to [callable functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) and invoke them from the web site with the Firebase SDK to invoke kthem.  Or not.

Comment: Thanks Doug, You're correct that we don't use any other firebase functionality in the SPA. So when I add those scripts I can indeed get the projectId out of the options property in the configured firebase app, however as far as I can tell this is only one part of the URL in question, with the other part being some sort of server location/region identifier (`us-central1` in my original question). This does not appear to be included in the options object, do you know where I would source that?

Comment: Yeah, you have to know what that is, even if you use a callable.  No way around that.

Comment: Oh, that seems weird, so there's no good way to allow a hosted app to be agnostic of it's project config? It just feels as though getting the cloud functions URL in a hosted app in the same project would surely be a common need with a simple solution.

Comment: Cloud Functions doesn't really have anything to do with Hosting, except for URL rewrites, where the function must absolutely be deployed to us-central1.

Comment: `firebase.app().options` returns `null` or `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the region and appId from the environment variables.

eg:

```js
console.log(process.env);
```

Check your firebase logs

```
{ ...
  ENTRY_POINT: 'server',
  X_GOOGLE_FUNCTION_TRIGGER_TYPE: 'HTTP_TRIGGER',
  FIREBASE_CONFIG: '{"projectId":"pid","databaseURL":"https://pid.firebaseio.com","storageBucket":"pid.appspot.com","locationId":"europe-west"}',
  X_GOOGLE_FUNCTION_NAME: 'server',
  FUNCTION_TRIGGER_TYPE: 'HTTP_TRIGGER',
  X_GOOGLE_GCLOUD_PROJECT: 'pid',
  FUNCTION_NAME: 'server',
  X_GOOGLE_GCP_PROJECT: 'pid',
  X_GOOGLE_FUNCTION_REGION: 'us-central1',
  FUNCTION_REGION: 'us-central1',
  X_GOOGLE_ENTRY_POINT: 'server',
  GCLOUD_PROJECT: 'pid',
  GCP_PROJECT: 'pid',
  ... ommited
}
```

Out of these `GCP_PROJECT`, `GCLOUD_PROJECT`, `FUNCTION_REGION`, `FUNCTION_NAME` should work. So for eg. `process.env.FUNCTION_REGION`

Not sure how reliable this will be.